# SQL Loop/recursion across multiple layers

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, recursion, layer

I'm a bit in over my head at the moment! Help me stackoverflow, you are my only hope.

The goal is to calculate required material quantities for final production SKUs using SQL and a few tables.

I almost have a working code for this, but it is a mess, so I would need help with the format, and if it is possible to do this some other way.

If a SKU has half-finished products, then materials needed for that need to be factored in and calculated based on the required half-finished product and amount for the final SKU.

I.E. If SKU 1001 Requires 0.2 units of half-finished product 9001. Then the material needed to make one 9001 needs to be multiplied by 0.2 for the material requirements for SKU 1001.

There are multiple layers of this, one finished product might end up needing 5 levels of different half-finished products.

As a bonus, production lead in days needs to be included to calculate the material requirement per day based on production forecast. (How many days before the production of final SKU half-finished prouducts have to be done)

I Think using CTE for this might be the right way, instead of unions but I cannot figure that out. After code is tables and sample data.

Code included. It's a mess.

```
SELECT
  FinalItem,
  MaterialItemCode,
  SUM(Quantity),
  ProductionLead
FROM
  (
    select
      '1' AS Lvl,
      ItemCode as FinalItem,
      ItemCode,
      MaterialItemCode,
      SUM(Qty) AS QUANTITY,
      zEndProduct,
      zSemiFinished,
      zMaterial,
      0 AS ProductionLead
    from
      StdBOM
      INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
    WHERE
      Qty != 0
    GROUP BY
      ItemCode,
      MaterialItemCode,
      zEndProduct,
      zSemiFinished,
      zMaterial
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      '2',
      I.ItemCode,
      StdBOM.ItemCode,
      StdBOM.MaterialItemCode,
      Qty,

      zEndProduct,
      zSemiFinished,
      zMaterial,
      ProdBuffTime AS ProductionLead
    FROM
      StdBOM
      INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
      INNER JOIN (
        select
          ItemCode,
          MaterialItemCode
        from
          StdBOM
          INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
        WHERE
          Item.zSemiFinished = 1
          and Qty != 0
      ) I ON I.MaterialItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
      AND StdBOM.Qty != 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      '3',
      FinalItem,
      BOM.ItemCode,
      BOM.MaterialItemCode,
      BOM.Qty,
      Item.zEndProduct,
      Item.zSemiFinished,
      Item.zMaterial,
      ProdBuffTime + S.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          I.ItemCode AS FinalItem,
          StdBOM.ItemCode,
          StdBOM.MaterialItemCode,
          Qty,
          zEndProduct,
          zSemiFinished,
          zMaterial,
          ProdBuffTime AS ProductionLead
        FROM
          StdBOM
          INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
          INNER JOIN (
            select
              ItemCode,
              MaterialItemCode
            from
              StdBOM
              INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
            WHERE
              Item.zSemiFinished = 1
              and Qty != 0
          ) I ON I.MaterialItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
        WHERE
          zSemiFinished = 1
      ) S
      INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on S.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
      INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
    WHERE
      BOM.Qty != 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      '4',
      FinalItem,
      BOM.ItemCode,
      BOM.MaterialItemCode,
      BOM.Qty,
      Item.zEndProduct,
      Item.zSemiFinished,
      Item.zMaterial,
      ProdBuffTime + T.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          FinalItem,
          BOM.ItemCode,
          BOM.MaterialItemCode,
          BOM.Qty,
          Item.zEndProduct,
          Item.zSemiFinished,
          Item.zMaterial,
          ProdBuffTime + S.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              I.ItemCode AS FinalItem,
              StdBOM.ItemCode,
              StdBOM.MaterialItemCode,
              Qty,
              zEndProduct,
              zSemiFinished,
              zMaterial,
              ProdBuffTime AS ProductionLead
            FROM
              StdBOM
              INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
              LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
              INNER JOIN (
                select
                  ItemCode,
                  MaterialItemCode
                from
                  StdBOM
                  INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
                WHERE
                  Item.zSemiFinished = 1
                  and Qty != 0
              ) I ON I.MaterialItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
            WHERE
              zSemiFinished = 1
          ) S
          INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on S.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
          INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
        WHERE
          BOM.Qty != 0
      ) T
      INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on T.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
      INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
    WHERE
      BOM.Qty != 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      '5',
      FinalItem,
      BOM.ItemCode,
      BOM.MaterialItemCode,
      BOM.Qty,
      Item.zEndProduct,
      Item.zSemiFinished,
      Item.zMaterial,
      ProdBuffTime + U.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          FinalItem,
          BOM.ItemCode,
          BOM.MaterialItemCode,
          BOM.Qty,
          Item.zEndProduct,
          Item.zSemiFinished,
          Item.zMaterial,
          ProdBuffTime + T.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              FinalItem,
              BOM.ItemCode,
              BOM.MaterialItemCode,
              BOM.Qty,
              Item.zEndProduct,
              Item.zSemiFinished,
              Item.zMaterial,
              ProdBuffTime + S.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
            FROM
              (
                SELECT
                  I.ItemCode AS FinalItem,
                  StdBOM.ItemCode,
                  StdBOM.MaterialItemCode,
                  Qty,
                  zEndProduct,
                  zSemiFinished,
                  zMaterial,
                  ProdBuffTime AS ProductionLead
                FROM
                  StdBOM
                  INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
                  INNER JOIN (
                    select
                      ItemCode,
                      MaterialItemCode
                    from
                      StdBOM
                      INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
                    WHERE
                      Item.zSemiFinished = 1
                      and Qty != 0
                  ) I ON I.MaterialItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
                WHERE
                  zSemiFinished = 1
              ) S
              INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on S.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
              INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
              LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
            WHERE
              BOM.Qty != 0
          ) T
          INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on T.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
          INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
        WHERE
          BOM.Qty != 0
      ) U
      INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on U.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
      INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
    WHERE
      BOM.Qty != 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      '6',
      FinalItem,
      BOM.ItemCode,
      BOM.MaterialItemCode,
      BOM.Qty,
      Item.zEndProduct,
      Item.zSemiFinished,
      Item.zMaterial,
      ProdBuffTime + Y.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          FinalItem,
          BOM.ItemCode,
          BOM.MaterialItemCode,
          BOM.Qty,
          Item.zEndProduct,
          Item.zSemiFinished,
          Item.zMaterial,
          ProdBuffTime + U.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
        FROM
          (
            SELECT
              FinalItem,
              BOM.ItemCode,
              BOM.MaterialItemCode,
              BOM.Qty,
              Item.zEndProduct,
              Item.zSemiFinished,
              Item.zMaterial,
              ProdBuffTime + T.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
            FROM
              (
                SELECT
                  FinalItem,
                  BOM.ItemCode,
                  BOM.MaterialItemCode,
                  BOM.Qty,
                  Item.zEndProduct,
                  Item.zSemiFinished,
                  Item.zMaterial,
                  ProdBuffTime + S.ProductionLead AS ProductionLead
                FROM
                  (
                    SELECT
                      I.ItemCode AS FinalItem,
                      StdBOM.ItemCode,
                      StdBOM.MaterialItemCode,
                      Qty,
                      zEndProduct,
                      zSemiFinished,
                      zMaterial,
                      ProdBuffTime AS ProductionLead
                    FROM
                      StdBOM
                      INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
                      LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
                      INNER JOIN (
                        select
                          ItemCode,
                          MaterialItemCode
                        from
                          StdBOM
                          INNER join Item on Item.Code = StdBOM.MaterialItemCode
                        WHERE
                          Item.zSemiFinished = 1
                          and Qty != 0
                      ) I ON I.MaterialItemCode = StdBOM.ItemCode
                    WHERE
                      zSemiFinished = 1
                  ) S
                  INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on S.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
                  INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
                WHERE
                  BOM.Qty != 0
              ) T
              INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on T.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
              INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
              LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
            WHERE
              BOM.Qty != 0
          ) U
          INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on U.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
          INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
        WHERE
          BOM.Qty != 0
      ) Y
      INNER JOIN StdBOM BOM on Y.MaterialItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
      INNER JOIN Item on Item.Code = BOM.MaterialItemCode
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead on ProductionLead.ItemCode = BOM.ItemCode
    WHERE
      BOM.Qty != 0
  ) BOM
WHERE
  zMATERIAL = 1
GROUP BY
  MaterialItemCode,
  ProductionLead,
  FinalItem
ORDER BY
  1,
  2
```

Tables and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE ProductionLead (
    ItemCode varchar(40) NULL, --This Includes Half-Finished Products
    ProdBuffTime float(53) NULL
)

CREATE TABLE StdBOM(
    ItemCode varchar(40) NULL, --BOTH Finished and Half-Finished Products
    MaterialItemCode varchar(80) NULL, --BOTH Half-Finished and Materials
    Qty real NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Item(
    Code nvarchar(450) NULL, --Materials, Half-Finished and Finished
    zEndProduct bit NULL,
    zMaterial bit NULL,
    zSemiFinished bit NULL
)

--SAMPLE DATA

INSERT INTO ITEM (Code, zEndProduct, zSemiFinished, zMaterial) VALUES
('51130',1,0,0),
('905111', 0, 1, 0),
('91010', 0, 0, 1),
('99400', 0, 0, 1),
('t81400', 0, 0, 1),
('t82002', 0, 0, 1),
('t82215', 0, 0, 1),
('t85062', 0, 0, 1),
('t85102', 0, 0, 1),
('904111', 0, 1, 0),
('91010', 0, 0, 1),
('t84100', 0, 0, 1),
('902100', 0, 1, 0),
('920903', 0, 1, 0),
('99405', 0, 0, 1),
('11016', 0, 0, 1),
('79997', 0, 0, 1),
('91001', 0, 0, 1),
('91010', 0, 0, 1),
('99403', 0, 0, 1),
('902160', 0, 0, 1),
('902702', 0, 0, 1),
('902704', 0, 0, 1),
('t80200', 0, 0, 1),
('t82432', 0, 0, 1)

INSERT INTO StdBOM (ItemCode, MaterialItemCode, Qty) VALUES
('920903','91001',0.872),
('920903','t80200',0.128),
('902100','11025',0),
('902100','11024',0),
('902100','11026',0),
('902100','11016',1.413),
('902100','11027',0),
('902100','11011',0),
('904111','902100',0.943),
('904111','902165',0),
('904111','920903',0.057),
('904111','99405',0.0028),
('905111','904111',1.1806),
('905111','t84100',0.006548),
('905111','91010',0.539),
('902100','901100',0),
('902100','99403',0.005),
('904111','901220',0),
('902100','t82432',0.0051),
('902100','79997',0.02),
('902100','91001',0),
('902100','91010',0.058),
('902100','902702',-0.0814),
('902100','902704',-0.0299),
('902100','902160',-0.001),
('904111','91010',0),
('904111','902160',0)

INSERT INTO ProductionLead (ItemCode, ProdBuffTime) VALUES
('905111',1),
('t82002',0),
('t85062',0),
('t81400',0),
('99400',0),
('t84100',0),
('904111',0),
('902100',1),
('99405',0),
('11016',0),
('99403',0),
('t82432',0),
('91001',0),
('79997',0),
('t80200',0),
('t82215',0),
('t85102',0),
('91010',0),
('902160',0),
('902702',0),
('902704',0),
('920903',0),
('11016',0),
('11016',0)
```

From these tables and data, I wish to get the total quantity of Items have zMaterial=1.

[image]

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Here is the code.

```
WITH RPL (PART, SUBPART, QUANTITY, ProductionBuffer) AS (
    SELECT StdBOM.itemcode, StdBOM.MatItemCode, Qty, ProductionLead.ProdBuffTime AS ProductionBuffer
    FROM StdBOM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ProductionLead ON ProductionLead .ItemCode=StdBOM.MatItemCode
    where Qty != 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT PARENT.PART, CHILD.MatItemCode, PARENT.QUANTITY * CHILD.Qty, PARENT.ProductionBuffer+PRODBUFFMAT.ProdBuffTime
    FROM RPL PARENT, StdBOM CHILD
    JOIN Digia_ItemLoc PRODBUFFMAT ON PRODBUFFMAT.ItemCode=CHILD.MatItemCode
    WHERE PARENT.SUBPART = CHILD.itemCode
)

SELECT PART, SUBPART, Material.zMaterial, SUM(QUANTITY), CASE WHEN ENNAKKO is null THEN 0 ELSE ENNAKKO END AS ENNAKKO FROM RPL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Item Material ON Material.Code = RPL.SUBPART and Material.zMaterial='Kyllä'
    WHERE zMaterial='Kyllä'
    GROUP BY PART, SUBPART, Material.zMaterial, ENNAKKO
    HAVING SUM(QUANTITY) != 0
    ORDER BY ENNAKKO
```